# Show a div on select value codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this dropdown

```
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for="LEAVE_ENTITLED"><span>*</span>Leave Entitled:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select class="form-control" name = "LEAVE_ENTITLED" id = "LEAVE_ENTITLED">
          <option></option>
          <option value= "Yes">Yes</option>
          <option value= "No">No</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide this one,

```
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for="SOLO_P"><span>*</span>Solo Parent ?<br>(If leave entitled)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select class="form-control" name = "SOLO_P">
          <option></option>
          <option value= "Yes">Yes</option>
          <option value= "No">No</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then when I selected yes on the first dropdown, it will show the second dropdown. how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i did is

```
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for="LEAVE_ENTITLED"><span>*</span>Leave Entitled:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select class="form-control" name = "LEAVE_ENTITLED" id = "LEAVE_ENTITLED">
                      <option></option>
                      <option value= "Yes">Yes</option>
                      <option value= "No">No</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="solop box-body" style="display:none" id = "Yes">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for="SOLO_P"><span>*</span>Solo Parent ?<br>(If leave entitled)</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select class="form-control" name = "SOLO_P">
                      <option></option>
                      <option value= "Yes">Yes</option>
                      <option value= "No">No</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

then my javascript is

```
$(function() {
    $('#LEAVE_ENTITLED').change(function(){
        $('.solop').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('.solop').hide();` is not really necessary. There is no class _solop_ in your code.
After selecting 'Yes' in first drop down, second drop down will appear. But if you change the first drop down to 'No', then second drop down doesn't disappear. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

By default, hide the second drop down on page load.
Then check the first drop down value to be 'Yes' and remove hide class for second drop down.

```js
$('#LEAVE_ENTITLED').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $dropdown2 = $('#ddlSecond');

  if ($this.val() == 'Yes') {
    $dropdown2.removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $dropdown2.addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for="LEAVE_ENTITLED"><span>*</span>Leave Entitled:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select class="form-control" name="LEAVE_ENTITLED" id="LEAVE_ENTITLED">
        <option></option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box-body hide" id="ddlSecond">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for="SOLO_P"><span>*</span>Solo Parent ?
      <br>(If leave entitled)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select class="form-control" name="SOLO_P">
        <option></option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why am I down voted? Please give your reason when you down vote someone